# Set color in pie chart in c#.net

Tags: c#, pie-chart

I am trying to create a simple pie chart using data extracted from a database in C#.NET. I have used following codes-

```
string[] xAxis = { "Banana", "Mango", "Apple" };    
double BananaPercentage= 40;
double MangoPercentage= 30;
double ApplePercentage = 30;
double[] Percentage = { BananaPercentage, MangoPercentage, ApplePercentage };

Color[] PieColors = { Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Gray };   

chart1.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT";
chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "#AXISLABEL";
//chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = PieColors[0];
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, Percentage);
```

It shows pie chart with correct values. But when I try to assign specific color for Banana(green), Mango(red) and Apple(Gray), it shows error "index was out of range. must be non-negative.....". 
Could anyone give me any hints what is wrong here ?

Comment: How to you assign specific color?

Comment: yes dear :) 3 specific colors for 3 specific values.

Comment: I assume the `index was out of range` exception relates to `Points` and not `PieColors`. Why do you expect the series to have points before you bind them?

Comment: I mean that where is your code that assigned specific color :) @CrackerBoy

Comment: actually, without assigning colors, it shows default colors. now i need to assign my specific colors.i used chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = PieColors[0]; to assign so. i am a bit new  :)

Comment: Are you sure that chart1.Series[0].Points array has any item?

Comment: chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color is getting items from PieColors[] array. isn't it so ?

Comment: I think @UğurAldanmaz is correct, try using `chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, Percentage);` before `chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = PieColors[0];`

Comment: yes, you are right. i solved it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"index was out of range..." is because of `chart1.Series[0].Points[0]` , especially `.Points[0]`. Not because of `PieColors[0]`. You should add some Points before, if you want to use them further or if you want to change their colors. For example :

```
int index = chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
```

and then you can do like:

```
chatr1.Series[0].Points[index].Color = PieColors[0]; //or whatever color
```

In your case, the problems is, you bind points to `chart1.Series[0].Points` after you try to assign Point's color. Try to change this :

```
chart1.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT";
chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "#AXISLABEL";
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = PieColors[0];
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, Percentage);
```

To

```
chart1.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT";
chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "#AXISLABEL";
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, Percentage);
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = PieColors[0];
chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Color = PieColors[1];
chart1.Series[0].Points[2].Color = PieColors[2];
```

If you want to change Series color, not Point, you can write something like:

```
chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red; //or any other color, maybe from PieColor
```

Answer (score 0):

this.CategoryGraphChart.Series["Categories"].Points.AddXY(test.ToString() + "(" + number + ")", number);

CategoryGraphChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;

CategoryGraphChart.PaletteCustomColors = new Color[] { Color.BlanchedAlmond, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow };

This code will work...